# System.StackOverflow error

Tags: windows, vb.net, microsoft-metro

I am working on a update to an existing Windows Store App written in VB.net.
I made a shared MsgBox() function and a "un-shared" one (which is to be run from the shared one). I need the shared one because I also run it from another class. The full error code:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in Calculator World.exe
The program '[4360] Calculator World.exe: Managed (v4.0.30319)' has exited with code -2147023895 (0x800703e9)
```

Here is the MsgBox code:

```
''' <summary>
''' Shows a message box with a Close button.
''' 
''' NOTE: Run "MainPage.MessageBoxDone = false" before running this function!!!
''' </summary>
''' <param name="text">The text to show in the message box.</param>
Public Shared Sub MsgBox(ByVal text As String)'<--- error is occurring  ether here 
    MsgBox(text)                          ' <--- or here
End Sub

Private Sub MsgBox_unShared(ByVal txt As String)
    Canvas_MsgBox.Visibility = Windows.UI.Xaml.Visibility.Visible
    Label_MsgBox.Text = txt
End Sub
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `MsgBox` function calls itself - resulting in infinite recursion and therefore stack overflow. You probably meant `MsgBox` to call `MsgBox_unShared`.

Comment: But how can you call an instance method from a Shared one?

Comment: Right, he either needs to make MsgBox_unShared also static or create an object instance in MsgBox.

Comment: Here is how I ended up doing it: MsgBox_unShared handles Shared Event MsgBox_event; and MsgBox raises it.